# Replacing special characters from URL with iconv doesn't work

Tags: php, string, url, url-rewriting, iconv

I have a small problem with some of my urls. Let's say `that $result['title']` = Citroën

In my url, I want this word to become "citroen". The following function does everything right, except that it removes the "ë", so my url becomes "citron".

```
<?php echo strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', str_replace(' ', '-', $result['title'])));?>
```

I thought I could solve this by using `iconv`... but it doesn't work. "Citroën" is still replaced by "citron".

```
<?php echo strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', str_replace(' ', '-', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $result['title']))));?>
```

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: have you consider using urlencode() instead. `echo urlencode('Citroën'); //Citro%C3%ABn `

Comment: Using urlencode gives me "citroc3ab".

Comment: I found the answer. I needed to set a target locale. `php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB');`

Comment: changing *ë* to *e* is like changing *h* to *f* so why not properly encode for the purpose, and for a url its `urlencode()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I need to set a target locale. The following code works (so "Citroën" becomes "citroen"):

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.utf8'); echo strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', str_replace(' ', '-', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $result['titel']))));?>
```